# How to get the largest number for each item in the table MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to get the largest number for each item in the table MySql

[image]

I want to have the most chosen name "name_p" everywhere "num_place"

```
SELECT name_p,num_place,COUNT(`id`) as couny_pla FROM selec_user GROUP BY name_p,num_place ORDER BY selec_user.num_place ASC
```

this result:-

[image]

But this is the result I needed

[image]

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 10. 4 .8-MariaDB

Comment: You may [edit] vital details into your question at any time.

Comment: What should happen in the event of a tie between two name_p & num_place counts?  Take the lower num_place?

Comment: Can you explain why `h` is not in the desired result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can produce your desired result but may arbitrarily either 'e' or 'h' for num_place 3, since they are tied:

```
select name_p, num_place, couny_pla
from (
    select name_p, num_place, row_number() over (partition by num_place order by couny_pla desc) n, count(*) couny_pla
    from selec_user
    group by name_p, num_place 
) ranked_groups
where n=1
order by num_place;
```

Replace `row_number()` with `rank()` if you want all tied values returned.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=9818b47f973cc8b5206bff00999277fd)